# Intellisense window has input field, and doesn't commit on space

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

All of a sudden, my intellisense window in VS2010 Express has a input field which has exactly what I'm typing. This wouldn't bother me, except that now space doesn't commit the selected choice that intellisense gives me.

Also note that the option in Tools-Options-Text Editor-C#-IntelliSense does have the "Comitted by pressing the spacebar" checked, yet it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Check if you are in "running mode", then stop the debugger and try! I had the same issue and after I recognize that i've to stop the debugger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you've messed with completion mode at some point.  This can be changed by going to  Edit -> IntelliSense -> Toggle Completion Mode or by just hitting Ctrl + Alt + Space

Comment: I must have hit it by accident, thanks! Some settings are just hard to put into words and find in visual studio.

Comment: It was the darn Ctr+Alt+Space that toggles this. Why, oh why did they put such shortcut. I cannot even figure out any use of that input field. Thanks @Yetti

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft finally fixed it.**

It looks like the state of completion mode (toggled by Ctrl-Alt-Space) is finally persisted and applied to new windows.

Set it the way you like it.  Close and reopen.  Start new windows.  It should stick to all of them.

**Version:  SP1 for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014**